# External login , in case internal login fail

Tags: users

I have a website which needs to authenticate users using drupal **users** table.

If authentication fails, then I want to run the authentication against users table from another database.

lf authentication is successful , then I want to register this user inside drupal, so the next this user next time he logs in , he get authenticated from drupal users table , not the external users table.

I wish to get a complete solution for that.

the following code is my attempt :

```
function external_auth_form_user_login_alter(&$form,$form_state){

$form['#validate'] = array( 'user_login_name_validate' );
user_login_authenticate_validate( $form, $form_state );
if(!empty($form_state['uid'])){

db_set_active('barakah');
$result=db_query('select username,password from users where username= :name   and password= :pass',array(':name' =>$form_state['input']['name'],':pass'=>$form_state['input']['pass']));
db_set_active('default');
if(!empty($result)){
$username = $form_state['input']['name'];
user_external_login_register($username, 'external_auth');

}




} 

}
```

but as if the code doesn't exist, nothing happens

Comment: Can't you just import the user from the old DB to Drupal?

Comment: You should extract user informations from the DB and use the User Import module : https://drupal.org/project/user_import. What might be tricky is keeping the password, it depends how it's encoded in your old database.

Comment: my solution should work, it is similar to many tutorials, but as if my code is not executing, external_auth_form_user_login_alter should alter user login form, but in my case it doesn't

Comment: This is never going to work with hook_form_alter. This hook is called when displaying the form, not on form validation. You should add a hook_validate on the form.

Comment: can you post a solution please ? modify my code and then let me copy it and try it for my self

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

[`drupal_external_login_register`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_external_login_register/7)

> Helper function for authentication modules. Either logs in or
>   registers the current user

An example implementation is detailed here:

https://api.drupal.org/comment/13434#comment-13434

Comment: you are absolutely right, but what i want is that external authentication undergo only if internal authentication fails, i hope that you got any clue for that.

Comment: i am doing this because i have upgraded a system to drupal, and i have users on the new website, and also i have users on the old website, when i tried solution for external drupal login, external login works, but internal login fails !

Comment: You just need to add the user login validate handlers in the correct order, so local drupal ones run first.

Comment: i edited the question, and i hope that you got any clue about why my code is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
function custom_user_validate_login_validate(&$form,$form_state){
    $form['#validate'][] = 'custom_user_validate_login_validate';
}

function custom_user_validate_form_user_login_alter($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message("Custom Validation"); //Just to check if the hook_validate is called
    user_login_authenticate_validate( $form, $form_state );
    if(empty($form_state['uid'])){ // remove the ! here
        db_set_active('barakah');
        $result=db_query('select username,password from users where username= :name   and password= :pass',array(':name' =>$form_state['input']['name'],':pass'=>$form_state['input']['pass']));
        db_set_active('default');
        if(!empty($result)){
        $username = $form_state['input']['name'];
        user_external_login_register($username, 'external_auth');
        }
    }
}
```

[Edit] Need to remove ['submit'] from hook_form_alter

[Edit2] Renaming the function names: replace custom_user_validate by your module name

[Edit3] Updating the name of hook_validate to match function names

Comment: i just tried it , it didn't work, not even print the custom message !

Comment: Just edited the answer, you need to remove ['submit'] from hook_form_alter

Comment: didn't work, not even custom message display

Comment: One last try: the hook validate gets called with this code.

Comment: Also, you should remove the "!" in front of empty